# How can I force NPM to look for installed packages in different folder?

Tags: node.js, npm, docpad

Messed Docpad installation.

Now Docpad is in /usr/bin/docpad /usr/lib/node_modules

While NPM look at /usr/**local**/bin/docpad /usr/**local**/node_modules

Can I specify proper directory for npm where it should look for installed modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up, removing Node.js and npm (installed from docpad scripts).

Installing again node.js and npm from chris-lea/node.js ppa.

Removing docpad by npm from ppa. And then node.js and npm them selfs, and then whole ppa.

Installing node.js and npm from docpad scripts.

Comment: Yes. I installed nodejs via ppa, and then from official sources. Those put npm packages in different folders. And I can not set my answer as solving, for next 26h.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to set the `$NODE_PATH` environment variable, check out the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders) for more details on loading modules.

Comment: noope that do not help. though npm docs refore to "prefix" shame that npm help prefix do not contain any info... How to set "prefix"?